# When handling an error in express where does next(err) lead?

Tags: node.js, express

http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html

```
function logErrors(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    next(err);
}
```

This code is in the expressJS documentation. I'm wondering what next(err) leads specifically. I know it's a callback function and you're passing in err, but what function will be called after an error?

Comment: It passes it onto the next middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It merely passes execution to the next error handler. So in the example you gave, the `clientErrorHandler` middleware would be executed and passed `err`.

Comment: Thank you! I would vote you up but I can't. I have an additional question. What would happen if you called, next() for the last middleware in the hierarchy. Would it cause an error?

Comment: `next()` passes execution to the next non-error middleware.

Comment: @AR7 I believe it would just hang and never respond.

Comment: @codenamejames It would return a 404 if no middleware sent a response.